# Configuring import paths - pycharm and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I've just recently started taking a graduate machine learning course this semester. I'm a math major, and had no experience with coding (maybe a little C++), and every single step seems to be a huge obstacle.

I've worked through some basics about python coding through a couple of Youtube courses and some short starting guide books. I have

- Installed python via anaconda,
- installed pycharm (professional - i'm a student),
- created a virtual environment with tensorflow via conda create,
- connected pycharm project to that environment,
- and added a new path for this project to import custom modules (I know that I can copy my modules to the site package folder in anaconda environments, but I thought it would be nice to keep a separate folder where I put all my modules for certain projects so that they are more accessible).

Now, here's what I want to do:

My professor specifically told us to turn in our assignments in jupyter notebook format (presumably .ipynb). I want to convert my python files (in a conda environment) in pycharm to a jupyter notebook file. I've tried but failed :

1. Convert .py directly into .ipynb (Is there a way to do this?)
2. create a new kernel via python -m ipykernel install, create new file under this kernel and copy-pasting my codes (I guess I can copy paste all my modules to this environment and it would work)
3. Using jupyter notebook in pycharm to begin with (I don't know but jupyter notebook for pycharm seems... inconvenient? maybe it's because I'm just used to the original jupyter notebook... )

I want to use pycharm as my base editor, and keep all my modules organized where I can easily access them, and have a convenient way to connect my pycharm projects to jupyter notebook.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

EDIT : I've now modified sys.path so that jupyter notebook can find my custom modules. But now I want to import mo models (.ckpt files) that I've trained to my jupyter notebook. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Jupyter comes with it's own web-based interface. Install jupyter nodebook & create a new notbook. Then copy your python code to the notebook & add other things as necesary

Comment: As I'v mentioned, there are some modules that I've added through pycharm path addition, so that when I just copy and run in jupyter notebook, it can't find the module. I know that I can copy all my modules to anaconda/env/.../site-packages , but I'd have to do so every time. I'm looking for a method to make everything "just happen". Any thoughts?

Comment: You can add your custom packages location to the PYTHONPATH or append it to `sys.path` to make them available.

Comment: Sounds great, can you elaborate plz? I'm completely new to python and don't know how to do neither of your recommendations, thanks!

Comment: Check out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168 You can add that to your jupyter notebook

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please give me tips on importing models (.ckpt files and such) to this notebook too? thanks